# Typescript, check if at least one is provided

Tags: typescript

I have following simple function

```
function takeOneOfOrThrow(firstOptionalVariable : string | undefined, secondOptionalVariable : string | undefined) {
    let result : string; 

    if ( !firstOptionalVariable && !secondOptionalVariable) {
        throw new Error('both are undefined'); 
    } 
    result = firstOptionalVariable ? firstOptionalVariable : secondOptionalVariable; 
};
```

Link to playground : https://tsplay.dev/mxJoxw.

both variables are string or undefined. First if eliminates the case that both are undefined or empty strings. therefore one of them for sure is string of length > 0.
Why then typescript gives me error there `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.` > What is proper approach to this problem ?

Comment: Add `!` to `secondOptionalVariable`: `result = firstOptionalVariable ? firstOptionalVariable : secondOptionalVariable!` ?

Comment: Typescript can't infer anything if you check if both of them are undefined. If you would change the condition to `!first || !second` then the compiler could be sure that both of them are not `undefined`, but with the current condition it's not clear which one of them exactly is not `undefined`. I would suggest not wasting your time on this and simply doing this: `result = first ?? second ?? ''`. Otherwise, you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQJAJN). Does this address your question? If yes, I'll write an answer; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame but this is point. Why compiler is unable to infer? There check properly checks for the case if both are udnefined so its easy to deduct and prove ( for human ) that after this check one of the variables is nonempty string. Why then ts compilar is unable to do that?

Comment: @chilly_maximus how the compiler should define that one of them is not `undefined` based on your condition? What you are asking for is to compiler analyze your js code, which is not possible

Comment: Well im not sure what you mean. Whole type checking is code analyze.   I have two viartbles both or of type string of | undefined and i did check for !a && !b. this catches case when a and b is undefined right ? Do i miss something ?

Comment: Imagine you are the compiler. The condition says if both of them are empty then throw an error. What type are you going to assign to variables after the condition?

Comment: (continued) you can't assign `string` to both of them, since it is not checked. You can't assign `string` to only one of them, since it's not correct and has no logic behind it. In your following ternary condition for the compiler there is no relationship between those two, thus it can't determine what you expect

Comment: ahhhhh yeah thx @wonderflame ! this explains everything.

Comment: Should İ write the answer with some alternatives?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254189/discussion-between-chilly-maximus-and-wonderflame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to infer types based on your condition.

Your condition checks whether both of the variables are `undefined`, however even if one of them is not, there is no way to infer the correct type for them since it doesn't make sense to make both of them just `string` because it's not what the condition checks. Also, the compiler can't infer just one of them as `string` since the compiler can't know until the runtime which one of them won't be empty. Thus, when you try to assign to variable there is no relation between variables and therefore you get the error.

One of the possible solutions is to use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) as the other answer suggests, however, I would recommend avoiding using it, since if the body of the function changes and the condition will be removed, the compiler won't raise any error.

The simplest alternative is to have a default value if both of the variables are empty, assuming that the default value won't be reached, because of the condition:

```
result = first ?? second ?? ''
```

Alternatively, you can use if/else blocks:

```
function takeOneOfOrThrow(firstOptionalVariable: string | undefined, secondOptionalVariable?: string | undefined) {
    let result: string;

    if (!firstOptionalVariable && !secondOptionalVariable) {
        throw new Error('both are undefined');
    }
    else if (firstOptionalVariable) {
        result = firstOptionalVariable;
    } else if (secondOptionalVariable) {
        result = secondOptionalVariable
    }
};
```